# Out of Memory errors in C#.net , Dotnet 2.0 pool

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, iis-express

One 32 bit c# application( dotnet 3.5, hosted on iis) is currently facing out of memory errors. The application is hosted as a service and it loads up the data(about 4 million records from db) into the memory cache( dictionary) every night. It was earlier running with 1.4 GB( w3wp.exe) and was highly unstable , so after removing the db data ( 17 million to 4 million), the memory was reduced to 0.4 GB which reduced the out of memory errors but they are still appearing.

RAM is available and I believe dotnet code shows this kind of error between 0.8GB to 1.2 GB. So, what could possibly cause this?

Any idea, if anything temporarily can be done as well without changing the code from iis or memory paging etc perspective.

Regards

Comment: You've posted just some observations of what is happening with nothing about what this app does, some sample code, etc.  We cannot help you.  -1.  As an outsider with no knowledge of this app by you reading this don't you think you'd agree with my assessment?

Comment: Unanswerable without specific details.  What's the rationale for bulk loading static data from a database into a dictionary?

Comment: Any chance to just run it as a 64 bit app?

Comment: Your application doesn't use RAM. It uses virtual memory and the address space for a 32 bit application is 2 or 4 GB regardless of how much RAM is available.

Comment: ram fragmentation issue can cause out of memory

Comment: @ alex : That's how the code is written and running in production..

Comment: @ tom tom :- yeah but that would require entire code change..something can be done to increase memory? It is failing while initializing that large chunk of memory. But on restarting, it is able to complete loading without any errors.

Comment: @ fredou : Yep I think the same but is there any temporary fix that can be done instead of removing logic to hold that much data or running it on 64 bit platform or run it as 64 bit app ?

Comment: @brian : thanks Brian for the clarification!

Comment: If the application is storing several million records in memory, my bets are that something was designed incorrectly.  Without having the problematic code available to us, and without knowing exactly what it's supposed to do however, any attempt is simply a shot in the dark.  My bets are that something like linq to sql (or even using a table adapter!) is probably a more viable option if the program actually needs to access all the data at once though.

Answer (score -1):

In .NET the maximum object size is 2GB.
If for any reason your object which is reading the data exceeds the 2gb threshold it will crash with the out of memory exception regardless of whether it is 32 or 64 bit or how much memory you have available.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241064%28VS.80%29.aspx

PS. Loading that much data into memory is not a good idea.